# Removed BIND9 from Debian Wheezy, Server IP still points to the Domain?

Tags: dns, ip, debian, domain-name, bind9

I have a Debian Wheezy Server that I installed BIND9 on it. I configured it to work with `example.com`, but now I wanted to change that to a differnet domain, `myOtherDomain.com`. I went through the zone file creation and removed all records that I found of `example.com`. But it still pointed to the same IP. So I went and removed the pacakge of BIND9 by `apt-get remove bind9` and `apt-get remove --purge bind9` but the IP still points to the domain. What am I missing? How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you still have a PTR record somewhere in DNS (the bind package != DNS) based on

> but the IP still points to the domain

There's not enough information in your post to be much more helpful than that. If you want to give actual details, there may be more that we can answer.

Comment: the real domain in question, your /etc/resolv.conf (linux) or DNS settings (windows), and is this a public or private DNS?